# Questions are locked for only 1 hour even if a longer duration is selected

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, locked-questions

To reproduce:

1. Go to Travel.SE (not sure if other sites are affected)
2. Pick any post
3. Lock it for 1 day or longer
4. Bug: after **1 hour** Community will unlock the post regardless of the setting above

Here's [a timeline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/118383/timeline) of one our posts where this happened twice.

Comment: Umm … It’s unrelated to this bug, obviously, but I don’t see the “content dispute” there. The edit does fix spelling and grammar mistakes and should be uncontroversial. Why the rollbacks?

Comment: @chirlu changed the link to a different locked question where the reason is more clear :)

Comment: Am I missing something? Looks like your example is locked for (what remains of) 24 hours right now. The default for "content dispute" is 1 hour - perhaps you forgot to change it?

Comment: @Shog9 I've tried to lock it again after I posted this bug report and the lock seemed to have taken hold now. However previously it didn't work and the lock was taken off after 1 hour.

Comment: Ok; I'm testing a theory here via a "permanent" lock. If this gets unlocked after an hour, that's the bug; if it doesn't, it's status-norepro.

Comment: Can't reproduce; tried here on meta and on Travel. Lemme know if you encounter this again please!

Comment: @JonathanReez any chance for userscripts on your side that might have somehow messed with the JS/HTML involved? (i.e. did you install any userscript related to SE?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it was some sort of a temporary glitch. It affected both me and another mod yesterday (as seen in the timeline) but then today all is well again.